# Xenfero pyhton notification bot

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a forum I am a member of and there is no notification system. I can pull data with python, but because I'm not logged in, it's pulling null data. Is there an easy way to login?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ="zenfero site link"
sayfa = requests.get(url)
html_sayfa= BeautifulSoup(sayfa.content,"html.parser")
isim =html_sayfa.find("span",class_="count")
print(isim)
```

Comment: Depends on the forum. This question cannot be answered with the information you've given.

Comment: r10.net forum  ?